# Increase the performance of script for loops

Tags: python

I wrote following *code* as shown below. When I put it into special *webpage's compiler* it generates some `test case scenarios` (I am not aware about inputs it does). My script gives correct results, nevertheless for (*i assume*) `performance tests case scenarios` it fails giving me message: *time for execution has been exceeded* (it shows that message if execution *exceeds 5 seconds*. **I consider to increase performance of my code.**
I suspect those lines to be time consuming:

```
if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty):
```

and/or this line:

```
  for i in unikaty:
            curr_frequency = tablica.count(i)
```

**How can I increase performance of my script regarding those loops?**

**Full script:**

```
def solve(N, A):

    tablica = []
    for r in range(0, N):
        tablica.append([[A[0][r],A[0][r+1]],[A[1][r],A[1][r+1]]])
        
    unikaty = []
     
    for r in range(0, N):
        if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty):
            unikaty.append(tablica[r])                    
     
    num = unikaty[0]
    counter = 0
    for i in unikaty:
            curr_frequency = tablica.count(i)
            if(curr_frequency > counter):
                counter = curr_frequency
                num = i

    return f'{sum(1 for x in unikaty if tablica.count(x) == tablica.count(num))}'                
                             
T = int(input())
if not(T >= 1 and T <= 10):
    quit()

for _ in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    if not(N >= 1 and N <= pow(10, 5)):
        quit()

    A = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(2)]

    print(solve(N, A))
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: @MobiZaman the problem is i just have this message: "Time limit exceeded" i do not see any stack trace so i have to assume what i wrote.

Comment: This mostly occurs when an infinite loop is running in the code. Can you confirm if that is not the case?

Comment: Please explain one thing to me. You are taking two inputs, T and N. After that, you are calling input.split() which expects two more inputs. Are you specifying these?

Comment: @MobiZaman Yes i do

Comment: Why do you keep the task secret instead of linking to it / describing it?

Answer (score 2):

```
for r in range(0, N):
    if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty):
        unikaty.append(tablica[r])
```

You can modifiing to (it's work if `tablica` consist tuples)

```
unikaty = list(set(tablica))
```

But I think that better solution - rewrite following lines to work with set structure `unikaty = set(tablica)`.

May be condition can change to:

```
if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty):
```

to

```
if tablica[r] not in unikaty:
```

And

```
num = unikaty[0]
counter = 0
for i in unikaty:
    curr_frequency = tablica.count(i)
    if(curr_frequency > counter):
        counter = curr_frequency
        num = i
```

to

```
num = max((tablica.count(i), i) for i in unikaty)[1]
```

And

```
return f'{sum(1 for x in unikaty if tablica.count(x) == tablica.count(num))}'
```

to (calculate invariant before cycle)

```
mx = tablica.count(num)
return f'{sum(tablica.count(x) == mx for x in unikaty)}'
```

And I think that f-string is excess and you can return int for `sum`.

One more way change type of `tablica` to tuple of tuples (if A[i][j] is hashable values) and use collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
def solve(N, A):
    tablica = (((A[0][r],A[0][r+1]),(A[1][r],A[1][r+1])) for r in range(0, N)),
    counters = Counter(tablica)
    mx = counters.most_common(1)[0][1]
    return list(c.values()).count(mx)
```

And check range like python style

```
for _ in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    if not(1 <= N <= 100000):
```

Comment: this line: unikaty = [r for r in range(N) if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty)] makes some other calculation as i have now wrong outputs comparing to oryginal code does. Can u check?

Comment: Sorry, wrote `r` vs `tablica[r]`. Checked.

Comment: Still smthg wrong with this

Comment: At this string wrong result?

Comment: yes, it gives then other results (wrong outputs at the end)

Comment: I reload answer. Try change only condition `not any`

Comment: i did, speed is still not enough

Comment: Result is correct after change? I dont have ideas why generator is not getting correct result. You are tried change `tablica` to tuple?

Comment: will check later (tuple). All works besides :unikaty = [tablica[r] for r in range(N) if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty)] which gives other results.

Comment: `unikaty = [tablica[r] for r in range(N) if tablica[r] not in unikaty)]` too?

Comment: And if you will change algorithm to work with collections than `unikaty` will be excess. Check my code for collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using **List Comprehension**:

Here's an exemple:

**Your code :**

```
for r in range(0, N):
    if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty):
         unikaty.append(tablica[r])
```

**With List Comprehension:**

```
unikaty = [tablica[r] for r in range(0, N) if not any(tablica[r] == x for x in unikaty)]
```

This should speed up you program execution.

Also try to avoid as much as possible using **for loop**, those are very resources consuming. **Instead use while loop** (it is recommended to use `while i=1` for infinity loop).

Comment: Using with your With List Comprehension i am getting diffrent (wrong) results